# Two values of ArcCos not showing

Tags: trigonometry

When I try to find

```
θ = ArcCos[-.5]
```

I am expecting more than one answer: $$2 \pi/3, 4\pi/3,...$$

But Mathematica is returning only one:
2.0944 and it is not in angle format as well. Is there a way to get all the values of angles in angle format?

Comment: Changing `-.5` to its rational representation $-\frac{1}{2}$ will tell Mathematica to use exact symbolic subroutines (and hence get your desired angle format).

Comment: That's done. But not giving more answers!

Comment: ArcCos is a multivalued, actually infinitely many, function. What do you think MMA should return? It has to choose one branch.

Comment: This is the same situation as `Sqrt[4]` returning only one out of two possible answers. Look up "principal branch".

Comment: `ArcCos` is a function, and functions, at least in modern mathematics, have only one value for each input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the equivalent

```
Solve[-1/2 == Cos[θ], θ]
```

and you get multiple values

Comment: But I am getting Solve[True, (2 \[Pi])/3]

Comment: `Clear[\[Theta]];
Solve[-2^(-1) == Cos[\[Theta]], \[Theta]]`

Comment: $$\left\{\left\{\theta \to \fbox{$2 \pi  c_1-\frac{2 \pi }{3}\text{ if }c_1\in \mathbb{Z}$}\right\},\left\{\theta \to \fbox{$2 \pi  c_1+\frac{2 \pi }{3}\text{ if }c_1\in \mathbb{Z}$}\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: It's working now...

Answer (score 5):

you could define a new version of `ArcCos[]` to produce the desired behaviour

```
arcCos[θ_] := Solve[θ == Cos[x] , x]
```

[image]